# Designing a multi-stage circuit

Tags: amplifier

I'm asked to design an amplifier with the following criteria:

- Mid-band gain = 71 dB [3548.13]
- Rin = 50 ohm
- Rout = 50 ohm
- f<sub>3db low</sub> = 8 kHz
- f<sub>3db high</sub> = 800 kHz

That is the first time I design an amplifier ever, so I need some basic instructions for a good start.
Here is my basic design :

[image]

My main question is how I can achieve a high gain cascading CE? Is it even possible or do I have to think about something else?

Comment: RB1 seems too low ?

Comment: Yeah. Pretty much nothing about that is good. And it looks as though you only know about one kind of stage. Much to say, little time or patience for it. Have you considered reading from Self or Cordell?

Comment: You need low input impedance (50 Ohm). So "Common Emitter" is not the best choice.

Comment: What would be the best choice to start  with ?

Comment: Stage xx with low-input impedance, only 3 choices.

Comment: Unless I made an error ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/C32tf.png here is an example of behavior. Do it for some other specifications you need. Then, make a "choice". There is some work to do. Sorry , Some words in french.

Comment: Five stages of common-emitter should be able to have gain near 10 million. First, get ONE stage biased correctly - its DC collector voltage should be no lower than base voltage (OP's circuit doesn't). Try to choose stage resistor values so that stage input resistance is higher than previous stage output resistance.

Answer (score 3):

Cascading EC topology may be certainly used. But ...

In any case, use a [simulator](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) for adjusting easily the first values of components. Use transistors as BF199 or others similar.

As the amplifier is used with low impedance (In/Out) (seems to be an RF amplifier with input/output impedance of 50 Ohm), for max power transfer (if this is needed), one needs a stage input with low input impedance (so BC) and an output stage with low output impedance (so CC).

For making a "good" choice, one must know first the specifications of the 3 base topologies circuits (EC, CC, and BC).
Here the methodology to do it.

First off all, a good **bias point**! Dynamic DC Analysis welcome.

[image]

At least : one must know ... for each topology, for one case here of components value,

**1**- input impedance

In order EC, CC, BC : 3k Ohm, 300k Ohm, 22 Ohm. So input stage may be a BC topology.

[image]

**2**- output impedance, calculated as usual : Zout= Uout (open output) / Iout (shorted output).

In order EC, CC, BC : 4.7k Ohm, 22 Ohm, 4.9k Ohm. So output stage may be a CC topology.

[image]

**3**- voltage gain with a frequency bandwidth

In order EC, CC, BC : 109, 0.99, 109. Bandwith : 100Hz -> 10 MegHz.

[image]

**4**- or power gain with frequency bandwidth

[image]

Next, assembling stages ... Voltage gain = 84 dB but Bandwith is not ok (only 100kHz). One can adjust it with a little "feedback" on the EC stage, adding a resistor in the emitter circuit.

[image]

For a better bandwidth, add an intermediate EC amplifier (more gain, but more feedback available with R19 and R24). Gain = 71 db, bandwith @3dB is now 1k -> 1Meg, well above requested. One can change this by lowering same capacitors ... well choosen.

[image]